Getting DataTables warning: table id=reportDataTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error,
Here is the js code i'm using
async function initDataTable() {
  try {
      const data = await getData(); // Fetch data
      const columns = Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => ({ title: key })); // Extract columns        dynamically
      $('#reportDataTable').DataTable({ // Initialize DataTable
         columns : columns,
         data :data
      });
  } catch (error) {
     console.error('Failed to initialize DataTable:', error);
  }
}

async function getData() {
  try {
     const response = await $.ajax({
         url: 'getData', // Assuming this is your server endpoint to fetch data
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
     });
     console.log("Response in getData:", response);
     return response;
  } catch (error) {
     console.error('Request failed with error:', error);
     throw error;
  }
}

I tried to get the columns dynamically which is displayed as expected, but the actual data is not present in the row. Instead getting

DataTables warning: table id=reportDataTable - Requested unknown
parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.

I tried to get solutions from the documentation but got lost again. Please help.

Please post your datatables initialization block as well.
